# How to fix 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()' in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to solve a class imbalance problem by randomly selecting the majority class equal to the minority class.

This is a multi-class classification problem, i've tried to sub-sample data with imbalance class distributions but i'm getting a boolean error. I've done label encoding for the classes.

```py
no_of_frauds = train.Suspicious.value_counts()
```

```py
non_fraud = train[train['Suspicious'] == 2]
intermediate = train[train['Suspicious'] == 0]
fraud = train[train['Suspicious'] == 1]
```

```py
selected = non_fraud.sample(no_of_frauds) #getting the error here
selected.head()
```

I expect the out to be a dataframe containing all the non-fraud items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this vector:
`no_of_frauds = train.Suspicious.value_counts()`

This doesn't gets you a integer, in which is used as an argument at the sample function.

Try instead `no_of_frauds = train.Suspicious.count()`